# MongoDB FIND method does not work in code

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

so when I try to find items in a collection through the console using the method db.DB_NAME.find({ x: y }, it works just fine. However, when trying to do the same in the code, it does not work.

Perhaps it is worthy mentioning that the method findOne works great within the code.

[Consulting through the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm4Xt.png)

Code:

```
app.get("/api/customer/:cpf", async (req, res) => {
  const properties = await Customer.consult(req);
  console.log(properties);
  res.status(200);
  res.end();
});
```

---

```
static async consult(req) {
    const conn = await client.connect();
    const db = conn.db("website");
    const cpf = req.params.cpf.toString();
    console.log(cpf);
    const properties = await db.collection("Property").find({
      customerCpf: cpf,
    });
    return properties;
  }
```

---

What I get from these pieces of code is a huge and weird (for me, a beginner) object in my console instead of the three expected objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i see you dont use mongoose.

What you get from `.find()` is an cursor. You need to convert it to an array:

```
const properties = await db.collection("Property").find({
  customerCpf: cpf,
}).toArray();
```

Comment: Nice to know it returns a cursor. I really appreciate your help, it works fine now!